# How do I do this integral?

Tags: integration

How do I integrate $$\int\limits_{-c}^c \frac{e^{-\gamma\, x^2}}{1-\beta \, x}\, dx $$, under the constraints (if necessary) that $\beta < 1\, /\, c$ and $\beta \ll 1$ ?

Comment: What is $\gamma$?

Comment: The first constraint is indeed necessary - without it, you'd be dealing with asymptotic behavior at $1/\beta$. However, the second is a little more unclear, since $\beta << 1$ doesn't have a formal definition, just an informal interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a bear of a time looking for exact solutions, since the indefinite integral will be in terms of the exponential integral function (Ei(t) = -$\int_{-t}^\infty \frac{e^x}{x} dx$), which is not an elementary function.

You can plug your integral into something like Mathematica to get $$- \frac{e^{ -\frac{\gamma}{\beta} } \text{Ei} \left( \left( \frac{1}{\beta} - x \right) \gamma \right) }{\beta}$$ and then, of course, it's plug and chug from there.

However, the fact that you were given the constraint $\beta << 1$ suggests that you may be interested in a numerical solution instead. In that case, you can approximate your function by $e^{-\gamma x}$ instead, which is close to your function in the range $(-\infty, \frac{1}{\beta})$ when $\beta << 1$ and is easy to integrate as $$\frac{e^{-\gamma x} }{ \gamma}.$$

Comment: thanks, sorry I forgot the exponential term is quadratic!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

- Using the exponential integral:
  $$\text{Ei}(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx}}{t}\space\text{d}t$$

---

$$\int\frac{e^{-\gamma x}}{1-\beta x}\space\text{d}x=-\frac{e^{-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}}\text{Ei}\left(\gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}-x\right)\right)}{\beta}+\text{C}$$

So with your boundaries we get:

$$\int_{-c}^{c}\frac{e^{-\gamma x}}{1-\beta x}\space\text{d}x=\left[-\frac{e^{-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}}\text{Ei}\left(\gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}-x\right)\right)}{\beta}\right]_{-c}^{c}=\frac{e^{-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}}\left(\text{Ei}\left(\frac{\gamma(\beta c+1)}{\beta}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{\gamma(\beta c+1)}{\beta}\right)\right)}{\beta}$$